# Just another, why my edit was rejected

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I made [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14164665) which was rejected in order to be substituted [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40374295/3).

Just out of curiosity,

1. why `Reject & Edit` and not `Accept & Edit`, since most of the changes in two "edits" are the same
2. How come the Community give me such a message `This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed` since it is a robot, is this because of the `Reject & Edit`?

Also a link to the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40374295/revisions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the reviewer really knows why they chose Reject & Edit, but to be honest I spot a few issues with both edits.

"It's working fine" is correct, and should not have been changed to "its working fine".

On the plus side, your capitalization of "I" is correct. The new edit failed to do that to the first "I".
In my opinion "ip address" should have been changed to "IP address", too.
Neither edit does anything about the title - this is an easy one to forget, though. I'll admit that I've often forgotten to fix the title myself when editing.

Only the original reviewer can tell why they choose "Reject & Edit", and not "Improve Edit".
If I had to venture a guess, I would gamble that "its working fine" is what made this reviewer decide to reject - as it introduces a grammatical error.

You also asked about the message you got - "This edit did not fix critical issues with the post". This is the standard reply that Community gives when an edit is rejected with Reject & Edit.

Comment: I have also realized that I shouldn't have changed the `It's working fine`